# Use of the word "fit"

Tags: word-usage

Is it as correct to say, "That closet will fit all my clothes" as it is to say, "All my clothes will fit in that closet"?

Comment: The closet will _hold_ all my clothes.

Answer (score 1):

It is more correct to say "all my clothes will fit in that closet," because "to fit" is an action that is performed by the clothes rather than the closet. People do say things like "that closet will fit all my clothes", but it's not technically correct.

Comment: "that closet will accommodate/house/contain all my clothes" is correct because these are actions of the closet.

Comment: 1- Why is it not 'technically' correct is what the OP seems to be asking. *To fit* can be an action performed by something that accommodates something else as well. Check *fit*, verb.